# IIS Express, typescript, where js file is stored

Tags: typescript, webpack, .net-core

I have an aplication in .NET Core and TypeScript. I want to know where file .js generated from TypeScript is placed. Because I don't understand why when I've made changes in my code in TypeScript I can't see these changes in generated js file.
This is my code in .ts file:

[image]
And when I run my app in VS and IIS Express in browser I still see old code, without line console.log:

[image]

The path of this file looks like this:

```
webpack:///./wwwroot/js/op_app/components/controls/opservertable.js?eb39
```

And in this file the code has changes:
[image]

Where this file is stored? How to clear it?

Comment: It may be that your index/main.html file gets cached by the browser. In which case you want to do a CTRL+F5 to force load it. Although I would have expected browserlink to take care of that for you...

Comment: Ctrl+F5 doesn't help. I use different browser and result is the same. So it would suggests that it isn't the browser matter.

Comment: If you look at the generated JS file on the filesytem, *not in your browser*, has it been updated?

Comment: If filesystem is correct, with console line

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with webpack?

Comment: If you look at the network tab in chrome debugger, what's the status code of the response for that particular file, and the html that references it?